# App.config of class DLL has info I need in web app

Tags: .net, configuration

I have a class library that I have built that includes several service references. In order to move the project forward I've copied the `<system.serviceModel>` config section from the app.config into the web.config. It works fine for now because I only have two references that I am tapping into at the moment. The problem I will be running into is that I won't automatically have any additional service references that I add into the library and my code will break if I call them without doing the copy and paste thing. What can I do to make sure that my WCF endpoints in the library app.config file are accessible to my applications automatically?

Comment: Could you consider configuring the endpoints programmatically in the class library instead of app.config/web.config?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734706(VS.85).aspx.  I believe it's possible to "include" a separate config file in another.  You'll need to make sure your class library's app.config file is deployed, and link it into the web.config.